# Write nested for loops in one sentence

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
list1 = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]
sentences = []
for row in list1:
    for i in row:
        sentences.append(i)

print(sentences)
```

With the output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
```

How can I write that in one sentence? This is what I tried:

```
sentences = [i for i in row for row in list1]
print(sentences)
```

This is what I got:

```
['g', 'g', 'g', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'i', 'i', 'i']
```

Comment: You need to write it from left to right `[i for row in list1 for i in row]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the loop correct

```py
[j for i in list1 for j in i]
```

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
```

Note:
If the loop goes like

```py
for b in a:
    for c in b:
        for d in c:
            ...
```

In list comprehension, it goes like

```py
[... for b in a for c in b for d in c]
```

Comment: Thank you, great explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Just need to give your list comprehension a switch in order.

```
sentences = [i for row in list1 for i in row ]
print(sentences)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
```

Comment: That's awesome. You learn something every day!

Answer (score 2):

x being the matrix

```
x = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]

 [val 
     for sublist in x 
        for val in sublist]
```

The first line suggests what we want to append to the list. The second line is the
outer loop and the third line is the inner loop.

Answer (score 2):

```py
list1 = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]
a =[i for row in list1 for i in row]
print(a)
```

Just swap the order